# Concisely parsing a pipe

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have lots of text output from a tool that I want to parse in Powershell 2.0.  The output is nicely formatted so I can construct a regex to pull out the data I want using select-string.  However getting the subsequent matches out of select-string seems long-winded.  There has to be a shorter way?

This works:

```
p4 users | select-string "^\w+(.\w+)?" | 
    select -Expand Matches | %{p4 changes -u $_.Value}
```

But All those Matches and Values are verbose.  There's nothing obvious in the select-string help file, but is there a way to make it pump out just the regex matches as strings?  A bit like:

```
p4 users | select-string "^\w(.\w+)?" -ImaginaryMagicOption | %{p4 changes -u $_}
```

Comment: Ok, in this p4 context, since I'm just looking for the first word of the output, I can use `p4 users | % {p4 changes -u $_.Split()[0]}`, but pretend I need the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it may be a bit easier to use `-match` e.g.:

```
p4 users | Foreach {if ($_ -match '^\w+(.\w+)?') { p4 changes -u $matches[0] }}
```

This is only because the output of Select-String is MatchInfo object that buries the Matches info one level down.  OTOH it can be made to work:

```
p4 users | Select-String "^\w+(.\w+)?" | 
    Foreach {p4 changes -u $_.Matches[0].Value}
```

Comment: In your first snippet, I actually want `$matches[0]` but otherwise that's awesome.  cheers.

Comment: I assumed you wanted just the group capture `(.\w+)` but if $matches[0] works for you that's cool.  I've updated the answer to reflect that.